# NoBackendError with Audioread

Tags: python, audio, librosa

I'm trying to use librosa.load() to load a midi file, but I'm getting a NoBackendError. In my conda environment I have installed ffmpeg 4.1 from conda forge, but it still gives me the error. I'm using jupyter lab, if that's relevent.

Thanks

Comment: can you do a pip freeze and check whether the library is installed